# How to combine rle with amount sum in R?

Tags: r, sequence, rle

I have a dataset of 0s and 1s and amounts attached to them,

```
test = data.frame(seq = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0), amount = c(91.0, 100.0, 0.0, 4.5, 5.5, 3.0, 23.0, 89.0, 56.0))



  seq amount
1   0   91.0
2   0  100.0
3   0    0.0
4   1    4.5
5   1    5.5
6   0    3.0
7   1   23.0
8   0   89.0
9   0   56.0
```

An event is defined by the first 0 in a subsequence of 0s. I am interested in the number of zeros (count) in each event, as well as the amount sums.

For *test* above, we would have:

- Event 1: 0 0 0, Amount: 191.0
- Event 2: 0, Amount: 3.0
- Event 3: 0 0, Amount: 145.0

So, I would like to create the following table,

```
|      Event |     count    |   amount |
|------------|--------------|----------|
|        1   |      3       | 191.0    |
|        2   |      1       | 3.0      |
|        3   |      2       | 145.0    |
```

In an earlier post, @27 ϕ 9 sent me this great suggestion for the *Event* and *count* columns.

```
with(rle(test), data.frame(id = sequence(sum(values == 0)), count = lengths[values == 0]))
```

But how can I add the amount sums still using **rle**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `data.table::rleid` to create group of consecutive runs, count the number of rows in each group and `sum` the `amount`.

```
library(dplyr)

res <- test %>%
  group_by(Event = data.table::rleid(seq)) %>%
  summarise(seq = first(seq), 
            count = n(), 
            amount = sum(amount))

res

#  Event   seq count amount
#  <int> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
#1     1     0     3    191
#2     2     1     2     10
#3     3     0     1      3
#4     4     1     1     23
#5     5     0     2    145
```

If you are interested only in 0 sequence -

```
res %>%
  filter(seq == 0) %>%
  mutate(Event = row_number()) %>%
  select(-seq)

#  Event count amount
#  <int> <int>  <dbl>
#1     1     3    191
#2     2     1      3
#3     3     2    145
```

---

If you are interested in continuing with the `rle` approach you can do -

```
with(rle(test$seq), data.frame(id = sequence(sum(values == 0)), 
                               count = lengths[values == 0], 
     amount = tapply(test$amount, rep(seq_along(values), lengths), sum)[values == 0]))

#  id count amount
#1  1     3    191
#3  2     1      3
#5  3     2    145
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much, @Ronak Shah

Answer (score 0):

In case there is no urged need to use `rle` `aggregate` could be used like:

```
i <- which(test$seq == 0)
aggregate(cbind(count=1, amount=test$amount[i]),
          list(Event=cumsum(c(1, diff(i) > 1))), sum)
#  Event count amount
#1     1     3    191
#2     2     1      3
#3     3     2    145
```

Or `rowsum`:

```
i <- which(test$seq == 0)
rowsum(cbind(count=1, amount=test$amount[i]), cumsum(c(1, diff(i) > 1)))
#  count amount
#1     3    191
#2     1      3
#3     2    145
```